# SWXMLHash EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, swxmlhash

I just converted my project to swift 4, but I having error when I emulate my app with SWXMLHash:

```
    var code: Int! = nil
    var message: String! = nil
    var paramsContent: String! = nil
    let xmlStrData = SWXMLHash.lazy(strData)

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let simulationParamsDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SimulationParams", in: context)
    let simulationParams = NSManagedObject(entity: simulationParamsDescription!, insertInto: context)


    code = Int((xmlStrData["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ns1:GetSimulationParamsResponse"]["GetSimulationParamsReturn"]["code"].element?.text)!)!
    message = xmlStrData["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ns1:GetSimulationParamsResponse"]["GetSimulationParamsReturn"]["message"].element?.text
```

When i'm trying to get the code node value, I get this error:

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely something is going wrong with the parsing here - most probably the structure of the XML response is not exactly what you think it is.

In general in Swift it's a good idea to steer away from force unwrapping optionals with `!` because if there isn't anything there you are guaranteeing that the app will crash. It's better to use `if let`s and `guard` statements, even if it makes the code uglier, just because it's safer.

To debug this, I'd rewrite your the last two lines as a series of `guard`s (not sure what the types involved are, so you'll have to fill in `$DICT_TYPE_HERE` appropriately).  You may not need to do it for every level, but I'd definitely avoid accessing 4-5 levels on one line - it's just asking for trouble.

```
guard let envelope = xmlStrData["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"] else as? $DICT_TYPE_HERE {
 //handle failure
 return 
}
guard let body = envelope["SOAP-ENV:Body"] else as? $DICT_TYPE_HERE {
 //handle failure 
 return 
}
.
.
until you find the problem
```

Ideally you should be using an XML object mapper, which allows you to declare Swift objects that can be translated back and forth to XML, but unfortunately I can't find an obvious one for Swift (there are loads for JSON, including the shiny new `Codable` protocol made by Apple itself).

Comment: I don't think that's the problem is here, it's because of SWXMLHash when I passed on Swift 4 I don't see data when I'm on debug mode